# Why can't I go on Minecraft Realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

So, I just updated to 1.11.1 and decided to go on my friend's realm to test all the new stuff out. When I do, it says "Minecraft now updated, you're still at 1.11" but when I look at the home screen it says "Minecraft 1.11.1" in the bottom left corner. I've tried restarting my computer, and logging out, then back it but it still hasn't shown any sign of helpfulness. I've even closed the game and opened it again.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that some or all of the Realms have not been updated yet.  We were able to connect with 1.11 but not 1.11.1.  Hopefully they will be loaded soon.